# Problems with MuseScore

Tags: sound, compatibility

I just installed Ubuntu on my Acer Aspire One 725, and started to install the programs I need for work. MuseScore doesn't seem to work well, I can't play the scores, and more importantly, while it runs, I don't get any sounds in other programmes (eg. on youtube).

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu!  ;-) What version of Ubuntu are you using? How did you install musescore? (Please [edit] your question and add the corresponding tag...)

Answer (score 2):

Go into preferences of MuseScope - **Preferences** -

**I/O** -

Under **Portaudio**

select  **Alsa** and choose the device (the first on the list usually works). Restart the Musescope.

[image]